# How do I customize the hotkeys on my Dell Latitude?

Tags: hotkeys, dell-latitude

My Latitude E6530 has a "Calc" hotkey which launches calc.exe by default.  I have no need for this application; how can I change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to this question in another forum (http://quomon.com/44379/Reprogramming-my-Dell-Keyboard-Hot-Keys).  The solution, which worked for me, is to edit HKLM/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/AppKey/18/ShellExecute.  The change was immediate, no need to log cycle.

I presume that the other elements within AppKey are also editable; if anyone else verifies this please edit it into this answer.